# Blanchard Kahn conditions are not satisfied: indeterminacy

Tags: rank

I am working on a real business cycle model. I am very new to Dynare programme. When I run the model, it says: There are 7 eigenvalue(s) larger than 1 in modulus 
for 10 forward-looking variable(s)

The rank condition ISN'T verified!

Error using print_info (line 45)
Blanchard Kahn conditions are not satisfied: indeterminacy.

Does someone have an idea how to overcome this problem?

```
var 
chat 
ihat 
    nhat
    qhat 
    Rhat 
    Rkhat 
khat 
    zhat 
    what 
    hhat
    xihat
    vahat
    vbhat
    nthat
    vthat
    shat
 ;
 varexo eps_z   
    eps_xi
    ;
parameters betta 
upsilon 
alppha 
phi 
delta 
lambda
epsilon 
theta 
siggma  
rho_z
sigma_z 
rho_xi 
sigma_xi 
covariance_z_xi
;
betta=0.9942;
upsilon=1.7167;
alppha=0.36;
phi=3.6;
delta=0.025;
lambda=0.1548;
epsilon=0.001;
theta=0.9685;
siggma=1;
rho_z=0.9315;
sigma_z=0.006424;
rho_xi=0.3744;
sigma_xi=0.0512;
covariance_z_xi=0;
model(linear);
#zstar=1;
#xistar=1;
#qstar=1;
#Rstar=1/betta-1;
#Rkstar=1/betta-1;
#nstar=((1-alppha)/theta*((1/betta-1+delta)/alppha)^(alppha/(alppha-
1)))/((theta+1-alppha)/theta*((1/betta-
1+delta)/alppha)^(alppha/(alppha-
1))-delta*((1/betta-1+delta)/alppha)^(1/(alppha-1)));
#kstar=((1/betta-1+delta)/alppha)^(1/(alppha-1))*nstar;
#cstar =(kstar/nstar)^alppha*(1-alppha)/theta*(1-nstar);
#ystar=(kstar/nstar)^alppha*nstar
#istar=delta*kstar;
#sstar=kstar;
#ntstar=(1-theta)/(1+betta*theta);
#vastar =qstar*sstar*(lambda/ntstar);
#vbstar=vastar;
#vtstar=0;
//1
1/(1-nstar)*nstar*nhat+siggma*chat=what;
//2
siggma*chat(+1)-siggma*chat=Rhat(+1);
//3
Rkhat(+1)*Rkstar=(zhat(+1)+(1-alppha)*khat+(1-alppha)*nhat(+1))*
 (nstar/kstar)^(1-alppha)+(qhat(+1)-qhat)*qstar;
//4
what=zhat+alppha*khat(-1)-alppha*hhat;
//5
vahat*vastar=xihat+vbhat*vbstar;
//6
qhat+shat=nthat-vthat*vtstar/(lambda-vtstar)+vahat;
//7
nthat*ntstar=(1-theta)*betta*Rhat(+1)*Rstar+betta*theta*((vahat(+1)-
vahat)+nthat(+1));
//8
vthat*vtstar=(1-theta)*betta*(Rkhat(+1)*Rkstar-
Rhat(+1)*Rstar)+betta*theta*(qhat(+1)-qhat+shat(+1)-shat+vahat(+1));
//9
vbhat(+1)*vbstar=theta*(Rkhat(+1)*Rkstar-
Rhat(+1)*Rstar+nthat+vthat*vtstar/(lambda-
vtstar)+Rhat(+1)*Rstar)+epsilon*vbhat;
//10
shat=khat;
//11
khat=khat(-1)-delta*khat(-1)-ihat*(istar/kstar)+(-phi*delta*(ihat-
khat(-1)))*istar/kstar;
//12
qhat*qstar=(phi*(ihat-khat(-1)))*(istar/kstar);
//13
hhat=nhat;
//14
chat*cstar/ystar+ihat*istar/ystar=zhat+alppha*khat(-1)+(1-
alppha)*hhat;
//15
zhat=rho_z*zhat(-1)+eps_z;
//16
xihat=rho_xi*xihat(-1)+eps_xi;
end;
steady_state_model; 
    chat=0; 
    ihat=0; 
    nhat=0; 
    qhat=0; 
    Rhat=0;
    Rkhat=0; 
    khat=0; 
    zhat=0; 
    what=0; 
    hhat=0; 
    xihat=0; 
    vahat=0; 
    vbhat=0; 
    nthat=0; 
    vthat=0; 
    shat=0; 
end; 
shocks;
var eps_xi; stderr 0.01;
var eps_z; stderr 0.01;
var eps_z,eps_xi=covariance_z_xi ;
end;
resid(1);
steady;
check;
stoch_simul(order=1,irf=20,periods=250);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually that means that there is a fundamental timing error in your model, typically related to the predetermined variables like capital or bonds or capital. Without knowing your model, this is hard to tell. Note that stackoverflow is probably not the right place to ask such a question. Dynare has a dedicated forum at https://forum.dynare.org/

EDIT following a post at https://forum.dynare.org/t/blanchard-kahn-conditions-not-satisfied-indeterminacy/10484/1: 
Your timing structure for capital seems correct, but the one for net worth is almost surely wrong.
If you have

```
vahat // bank net worth (after the shock) deviations from trend
vbhat // bank net worth (before the shock) deviations from trend
```

then the second one must be predetermined with respect to the shock at time t. But how can they then be contemporaneously related as in

```
vahat*vastar=xihat+vbhat*vbstar;
```